# How do I stream SMI glasses eye tracker data into MATLAB?

Tags: measurement, vision, eye-movement, cognitive-load, matlab

We are planning to use the **[SMI glasses eye tracker](https://www.smivision.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/smi_prod_ETG_120Hz_asgm.pdf)**. This eye tracker obtains gaze data and we will use it for pupillometry as a measure of cognitive load.

The only thing I'd like to accomplish is **streaming the eyetracker data in real-time to a running psychophysics MATLAB script** to sync the eyetracker data with a listening task.

Now, SMI's REDn system (the tabletop variant) comes with a MATLAB toolbox, but SMI's glasses don't. The glasses are a mobile application that allows the subject to wear the eye tracker as glasses. Hence, the subject can move around and doesn't have to fixate at a certain point.

Now I was wondering if there is anyone out here that has used SMI's eye tracking glasses with a MATLAB plugin? I'd prefer a low-budget solution, preferably a freeware MATLAB tool.

I am aware of [Lab Streaming Layer](https://www.neurobs.com/pres_docs/html/03_presentation/06_hardware_interfacing/02_lab_streaming_layer.htm) (LSL), but I can't get that to work, because of a version issue. Basically, LSL is written for a previous software development kit (SDK) for the eyetracker driver software (iView) and the current SDK is incompatible. SMI doesn't support previous SDK versions and hence that's a dead end.

I am also aware of various commercial plugins, such as [iMotions](https://imotions.com/portfolio-items/smi-eye-tracking-glasses/), but those are heavy, expensive toolkits for purposes far exceeding the simple streaming of data from the eyetracker to a running MATLAB script.

Answer (score 2):

Philip from iMotions here. Appreciate the mention, and yes for a simple streaming of data, our solutions are probably overkill. We do however offer real automatic gaze mapping in the cloud as well as auto segmentation which saves **a ton** of time

We also offer LSL in our [latest version](https://imotions.com/70-release/) but yes SMI doesn't support the previous SDK.

I'll listen in and hope someone can help you with your inquiry.

Comment: Hi Philip. ;) Great you found this site and took the time to reply! However, will have to stay impartial here and point out this is more of a comment than an answer. Especially given that @AliceD is only interested in cognitive load (through pupillometry) for this particular study for which I believe the described features are unlikely to be helpful (depending on the stimuli which are not described).

Comment: Perhaps more relevant to describe the easy addition of GSR and replay functionality in iMotions for a more reliable cognitive load measure and easier early exploration of data?

Comment: Welcome to CogSci and thanks for your reply here. It's interesting to see that iMotions combines with LSL.